# How to find lcm of two numbers efficiently (With out using any module like `np.lcm`)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lcm

I get this from the internet but it takes about 1 minute for the large numbers.

```py
import time

def lcm(x,y):
    if x>y:
        greater=x
    else:
        greater=y
    while(True):
        if((greater%x==0) and (greater%y==0)):
            lcm=greater
            break
        greater+=1
    return lcm

a = time.time()
num1 = 50342
num2 = 10000
print(f"Lcm of {num1} and {num2} is {lcm(num1,num2)}")

print("Time taken:", time.time() - a)
```

** OUTPUT **

```
Lcm of 50342 and 10000 is 251710000
Time taken: 39.7167
```

Is there a way to change this function and get the same result Fastly,

##### Note: Without using any module like `np.lcm`

Comment: This seems better suited for Code Review as you've got a working implementation.

Comment: You can find the lcm using the gcd with [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Using_the_greatest_common_divisor). The gcd can be found efficiently with the [euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a try on this,have a check plz

```
def hcf(a,b):

    if a == 0:

        return b

    return hcf(b % a, a)
 

def lcm(a,b):

    return a * b / hcf(a,b)
 

a = 15

b = 30

print('LCM of', a, 'and', b, 'is', lcm(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: GCF, GCD, and HCF are the same. All names are used to represent a similar method of finding the highest or greatest common factor/divisor.**

Yes, there's a fast way to do that.

There is a relationship between LCM and HCF.

> a x b = HCF(a, b) x LCM(a, b)
> Here, LCM(a, b) = HCF(a, b) / (a x b)

Finding HCF is an easy and fast way, therefore, using this relation you can get the same result easily and fastly.

```py
import time

def hcf(x, y):
    smaller = min((x, y))
    for i in range(1, smaller + 1)[::-1]: # Here I am reversing the range Now it is going from larger to the smaller number because the HCF Stand For the Highest Common Factor.
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i
            return hcf


def lcm(x,y):
    return round((x*y)/hcf(x,y))

a = time.time()
num1 = 50342
num2 = 10000
print(f"Lcm of {num1} and {num2} is {lcm(num1,num2)}")

print("Time took:", time.time() - a)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Lcm of 50342 and 10000 is 251710000
Time took: 0.00531005859375
```

I hope someone finds it helpful .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also.

```py
num1 = 12
num2 = 14
for i in range(max(num1, num2), 1 + (num1 * num2)):
    if i % num1 == i % num2 == 0:
        lcm = i
        break
print("LCM of", num1, "and", num2, "is", lcm)
```

Comment: BUt this is not fast?